# Construct a bounded infinite sequence $x_0, x_1, x_2,$ . . . such that $|x_i − x_j ||i − j|^a ≥ 1$

Tags: sequences-and-series

Given any real number $a > 1$, construct a bounded infinite sequence
$x_0, x_1, x_2,$... such that
$$|x_i − x_j||i − j|^{a} ≥ 1$$
for every pair of distinct nonnegative integers $i, j$.

This means that every adjacent number in the sequence must differ by at least 1 and no two numbers can be identical. And yet it must be bounded.

After quite a bit of tinkering I think I found a sequence which works, illustrated below:

[image: Sequence]

The idea is to cycle through the numbers 1 to 10 and then shift the starting point for the cycle ever so slightly for each cycle. The key point was to make sure that $|x_{i+10} − x_i| \ge 1/10$.

The formula for the sequence is (I think)

$$x_k = 1 + \sum_{i=0}^\infty 10^{-i}(((k-1) div 10^{i}) mod 10)$$

I have 2 questions:

a) How do I prove the above sequence works?

b) What sequence, fulfilling the requirements, is the "smallest", i.e. has the smallest distance between the supremum and the infimum of the sequence?

Comment: Nice construction! Two observations: (1) You can also define $x_k$ as (10 times) the decimal formed by reversing the digits of the integer $k$. This isn't exactly the same as yours at multiples of 10, although I think either choice works. (2) There are versions in other bases as well, for example the binary version $\{x_k\} = \{0, 1/2, 1/4, 3/4, 1/8, 3/8, 5/8, 7/8, \dots\}$ (or rather some constant multiple of this sequence, to get the lower bound $1$ instead of some other constant).

Comment: As for a proof, note that if the indices are not congruent modulo $10^m$, then the outputs differ by at least $10^{m-1}$ (perhaps a bit worse as one wraps around powers of $10$). This should be enough to prove the desired statement for $a=1$.

Comment: @Greg Martin - Thanks! I'll give your proof suggestion a shot.